How to find the number of rows within a group since a nonzero value occurred for a pandas dataframe?
I have a dataframe like so:



ID
value




A
0


A
1


A
0


A
0


B
0


B
0


B
2


B
0


B
4


B
0



I want to add a column that counts the number of rows since a nonzero value occurred within the group (in this case ID). The result would look like:



ID
value
num_rows_since_nonzero




A
0
0


A
1
0


A
0
1


A
0
2


B
0
0


B
0
0


B
2
0


B
0
1


B
4
0


B
0
1




Create a mask where to check if the group first values are 0. After that create the groups with the column ID and with the values from the column 'value' who are higher than 0. Use the mask to replace the values where the groups have 0 as the first value.
m = df.groupby('ID')['value'].cumsum().gt(0)
g = df['value'].gt(0)
df['rows_since_zero'] = df.groupby(['ID', g.cumsum()]).cumcount().where(m, 0)

ID  value  rows_since_zero
 A      0                0
 A      1                0
 A      0                1
 A      0                2
 B      0                0
 B      0                0
 B      2                0
 B      0                1
 B      4                0
 B      0                1


nice one!  Great logic.  +1

You can group by the ID and do a custom count function for each group.
def calc_nonzeros(grp):
    cnt = 0
    res = []
    for val in grp:
        if val != 0:
            cnt = 0
        res.append(cnt)
        cnt += 1
    return res


df["num_rows_since_nonzero"] = df.groupby("ID")["value"].transform(
    calc_nonzeros
)

